# Update variable value via add_filter

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks

I have this apply filter in my plugin.

```
$pre_html = apply_filters( 'events_views_html', null, $view_slug, $query, $context );
```

I want to change `$view_slug` value dynamically from child theme using `add_filter` because I do not want to modify plugin files. But this code is not working. It is displaying value of `$view_slug` instead of displaying complete page content.

```
function add_extra_val( $view_slug, $query, $context  ){
    if (is_singular('tribe_events')) {
        $view_slug = 'single-event';
    }
    return $view_slug;
}

add_filter('events_views_html', 'add_extra_val', 10, 3);
```

It is a basic question but I have limited knowledge of WordPress filters and hooks. Some guidelines regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Filters only allow you to directly modify the **first** value passed to them. In your case, that's `null`. If you shifted `view_slug` up a place, it would be available to filters using your `events_view_html` tag.

```
add_filter( 'events_view_html', 'my_callback', 10, 3); // passing 3 args to the callback, assuming you need them for something.

function my_callback( $view_slug, $query, $context ) {
// Do whatever you need to do to $view_slug
// $query and $context can be read but not changed
return $view_slug;
}
```

Comment: I tried this already but the page content is not displaying. Page only displaying the updated value of variable $view_slug.

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code.

Comment: I added my add_filter code above in my question.

Comment: Still no way of knowing what your plugin does with `view-slug`. that's probably where your problem lies. the filter itself looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is an example to modified the value using the add_filter hook:

// Accepting two arguments (three possible).
function example_callback( $view_slug, $query ) {
    ...
    return $maybe_modified_value;
}
add_filter( 'events_views_html', 'example_callback', 10, 2 ); // Where $priority is 10, $accepted_args is 2.
```